# Is it possible to "stream" a remote headless browser in an interactive way via puppeteer (or otherwise)?

Tags: google-chrome, streaming, virtual-machine, puppeteer

My use case is that I would like to automate the majority of a test that navigates through a series of pages, but would like a user to be able to manually intervene at particular points in that series.

Ideally this would look something like the following:

- user has a simple web-based client that launches the browser via puppeteer on a remote machine (say, via some REST call or something)
- once the automated navigation kicks off, the user can essentially see the remote browser "streamed" to their browser, in a way that allows them to interact with it
- in effect the user would be running a separate browser within their browser

Is there anything in Puppeteer that would allow me to do something like this?  If not, what approaches should I look at that may work?

Comment: Any update on this? I'm looking for something similar